# Which style of link is preferred?

Tags: discussion

There are two different styles of link - inline:

```
[example](http://example.com)
```

and citation:

```
[example][1]

  [1]:  http://example.com
```

Is there any preference for one over the other? Which do you think is best and why?

Comment: Seeing as how StackExchange by default uses the 'citation' style, I'd say that is the preferred one.

Comment: I personally think citation style is bad style and goes against the idea of MarkDown (being also readable in markup form).